# How do I register code to run when shutting down an ASP.NET web application using the new .NET 6 format?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Does anyone know how to get something to hit off when a .NET Core 6 website is closed? I've looked online and I keep seeing `Startup.cs` explanation but with the new .NET Core 6 this was removed and all we have is `Program.cs` now.

I'm trying to run a database script when the application is closed to update all the users to offline otherwise when the application is closed all the users stay online because the users haven't been able to 'Logout' to run a database script to update their status to offline.

Comment: Please define precisely what you mean by "website is closed" or "user closes the website down"

Comment: Run the script when the application starts.

Comment: Also, it's not clear that the application shutting down should mean that the users are logged off. In a RESTful application, being "logged in" does not imply having an active connection.

Comment: How would you suggest I would do this, would it be on the session timeout? Looking for advice :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your startup you can use the injected `IHostApplicationLifetime` for that ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)). For example:

```cs
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime, TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
        {
            hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => { telemetryClient.TrackEvent("App Started"); });
            hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => { telemetryClient.TrackEvent("App Stopping"); });
            hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => {
                telemetryClient.TrackEvent("App Stopped");
                telemetryClient.Flush();

                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
        }
```

For .Net 6 see [this code example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0#aspnet-core-6-8)

Comment: When stopping the application via 'Stopping Debug' on Visual Studios it doesn't hit this off. Why is this?

Comment: 'Stop Debug' is more of a _termination_ than a shutdown.

Comment: @sambbailey by 'stopping debug' you are not giving the application to shutdown gracefully. It is more like killing the process.